# Does oracle10g client( version 10.2.0.4) compatible with windows server 2008 6.1 standard 64 bit service pack 1

Tags: windows, oracle, server, oracle10g

Does oracle 10g client( version 10.2.0.4) compatible with windows server 2008 6.1 standard 64 bit service pack 1

Comment: Why do you want to install a 15 years old software?

Comment: Yes it's because some legacy components require this in my .net app

Answer (score 1):

According to Metalink, yes.

- 64-bit 10.2.0.**4** client is certified on MS Windows 2008 64-bit
- 64-bit 10.2.0.**5** client is certified on MS Windows 2008 R2 64-bit

For more info, check Doc ID 1231433.1.

Comment: Thanks , i am able to install it  via patch